# Access the outer fragment from the inner fragemt

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to access the outer fragment from the inner fragment so that the so that callbacks can be sent to the outer fragment. my current code of inner fragment is this

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (!(activity instanceof PageFragmentCallbacks)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement PageFragmentCallbacks");
        }

        mCallbacks = (PageFragmentCallbacks) activity;
    }
```

this works when the fragment is in the activity and the activity implements PageFragmentCallbacks. i need to make outer Fragment implements PageFragmentCallbacks.

Now to make this work in the nested fragment class i need access the outer fragment. How can i get the the outer fragment from the inner fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getParentFragment()` method to get parent (outer as you say) fragment, if it exists.

So in your `onAttach` method you can check if parent fragment is null or not. And check whether it implements your Callbacks, like you do it with activity.

**Update**
Example

```
     @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            if (activity instanceof PageFragmentCallbacks) {
                         mCallbacks = (PageFragmentCallbacks) activity;
            }
else if (getParentFragment()  instanceof PageFragmentCallbacks) {
                   mCallbacks = (PageFragmentCallbacks) getParentFragment();
            }
        }
```

You can also add one more else for getParentFragment().getParentFragment() if needed

Comment: Any more insight on this answer? doesn't seem to be working when I'm nesting an inner fragment inside an outer fragment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch what do you mean. I've added example. Sorry for indentation, written on phone. Does it help you?

Comment: getParentFragment() seems to always be null (in nested fragment)

Comment: Never mind, the trick was to use `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager` when adding the inner fragment from the outer fragment. Thanks +1